# Why '$array[]' and 'array_push' can't add more value?

Tags: php, mysql

PLEASE HELP ME!!

I want to convert a txt file into database.

I Have 2 table and it have a relationship.

Here is my DB:

```
OLT
----
id_olt
onu_number
type
serial_num

ONU
----
id_onu
id_olt
name
```

And here is the example for my data (*.txt)

```
"interface gpon-olt_1/2/1
  onu 1 type ZTEG-F660 sn ZTEABCDABCD
  onu 2 type ZTEG-F660 sn ZTEABCDABCD
  onu 3 type ZTEG-F660 sn ZTEABCDABCD
!
interface gpon-onu_1/2/1:1
  name Alex
!
"
```

Here my code :

```
// some reading file's code
...
if (strpos($values, $cari='interface gpon-olt_') !== false) {
if(strpos($values, $cari='  onu ') !== false){
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO olt (id_olt, onu_number, type, serial_num)
values ('','$onu_num',$type','serial_number') ");
...
```

So, every $sql running,  i want to catch its ID, then i put this :

```
$simpanidd = mysql_query("SELECT max(id_olt) from olt");
$simpanid = mysql_fetch_row($simpanidd);
```

But every time i run that, its show:

```
Array ( [0] => 96 [max(id_olt)] => 96 )
Array ( [0] => 97 [max(id_olt)] => 97 )
```

Its look like a new value was befall the previous value. I DONT WANT it ;(

Then i try to make '$simpanid' into an array '$simpanid[]', but it shows:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 94 [max(id_olt)] => 94 ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 94 [max(id_olt)] => 94 )
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 95 [max(id_olt)] => 95 ) )
```

Please somebody help me?
I'm so confuse...

(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: `$simpanid =  array(); while ($row =  mysql_fetch_row($simpanidd)){$simpanid = $row;}`. check it. And stop using deprecated+removed library `mysql_*`. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` along with `prepared statement`

Comment: It still show  Array ( [0] => 104 ) Array ( [0] => 105 ) ..

Comment: can you show that HOW's your query running multiple time? I am seeing that it runs only once through your current code

Comment: i'm sorry, i forget to say that my code was in a looping (while), and it will read a file line by line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do is just get the insert_id

```
$simpanid = mysql_insert_id();
```

after your `mysql_query()` you will get the id generated for that query